# Using select() for nonblocking serial

Tags: c++, linux, select, serial-port

I'm working on a project in which I need to read and write data from a serial port, and this needs to be non-blocking for reasons I won't go into.  The select() function looks like what I want to use, but I'm struggling with getting a working implementation.

In open_port() I define the settings for the port and that it is non-blocking. In otherselect() I assign the descriptor to the open_port() and attempt to read.  I also have a 1 second sleep call at the end of the function to attempt to avoid the reading being too fast for hardware.

When running I get a message printing out every second for "no data available" before I send the message, and after I send a message it prints it out, but it is usually in pieces with binary characters along with it. For example, when sending the word "buffer" it will print "ffer" followed by a binary character.

I have almost no experience with termios or select, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "termios.h"
#include "errno.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "sys/select.h"

using namespace std;

int open_port(){
struct termios oldtio,newtio;
int serial_fd;
if ((serial_fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_EXCL | O_NDELAY)) == -1) {
    cout << "unable to open" << endl;
    return -1;
}
if (tcgetattr(serial_fd, &oldtio) == -1) {
    cout << "tcgetattr failed" << endl;
    return -1;
}
cfmakeraw(&newtio); // Clean all settings
newtio.c_cflag = (newtio.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8 | B115200; // 8 databits
newtio.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
newtio.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD); // No parity
newtio.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // No hardware handshake
newtio.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // 1 stopbit
newtio.c_iflag = IGNBRK;
newtio.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // No software handshake
newtio.c_lflag = 0;
newtio.c_oflag = 0;
newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 60;
if (tcsetattr(serial_fd, TCSANOW, &newtio) == -1) {
    cout << "tcsetattr failed" << endl;
    return -1;
}
tcflush(serial_fd, TCIOFLUSH); // Clear IO buffer
return serial_fd;
}

void otherselect(){
fd_set readfs;
timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
char * buffer = new char[15];
int _fd = open_port();
FD_ZERO(&readfs);
FD_SET(_fd, &readfs);
select(_fd+1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, &tv /* no timeout */);
if (FD_ISSET(_fd, &readfs))
{
    int r = read(_fd, buffer, 15);
    if(r == -1){
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
    cout << buffer << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "data not available" << endl;
}
close(_fd);
sleep(1);
}

int main() {
    while(1){
        otherselect();
    }
}
```

Comment: as it's C++, have you considered using boost::asio for this?

Comment: Wouldn't you need `O_NONBLOCK` to your open() call to actually make it non-blocking? Edit: IIRC, `O_NDELAY` just skips waiting for DCD, while `O_NONBLOCK` actually just goes on without waiting for any input.

Comment: O_NDELAY is set equal to O_NONBLOCK in fcntl.h, they are equal.  I haven't looked into boost::asio yet, and I'll do that now, but I really like being given the option on how to handle if there is data with select()

Comment: `read()` doesn't add a terminating `'\0'` so how is your `cout << buffer` supposed to know where the string ends?

Comment: why do you keep opening and closing the port inside your loop?

Comment: when I change the last cell in the array to NULL before the printout it doesn't have any effect, but good catch.  Closing the port was my solution to opening far too many by accident, but I think I'll move the opening outside of the loop instead

Comment: Only opening the port once now and passing int as parameters, but still getting the same result

Comment: It's not just the last cell in the array you have to worry about. You can't assume that because read() didn't return -1, it must have returned the full amount you asked for. That's not how read() works. It's allowed to return anything from 1 to the size of your buffer, or 0 for EOF or -1 for error. You need to tell cout to print only the first `r` characters from the buffer. Don't know how to do that since I'm not a C++ guy

Comment: @AlanCurry: cout.write(buffer, r)

Comment: only printing the first 15 characters of the buffer results in not printing anything at all, it will skip printing anything

Comment: You leak memory. You should delete the `buffer` when the function ends. (or allocate it automatically/statically...)

Answer (score 1):

When you use read() you don't get a null terminated string, so

```
cout<<buffer<<endl
```

is obviously a bad idea. 
Do a,

```
buffer[r]='\0'  #(provided r<15)
```

before you print it out.